# How to fix a class method function from a module giving a variable not defined error

Tags: python, windows

So I am trying to create a simpler logging module, but I keep getting errors that make no sense.

The module is located in `%appdata%/python/site-packages/loggingLocal/__init__.py`

The modules code is as follows:

```
class Logger:

    def __init__(self):

        pass

    @classmethod

    def llog(cls, file, typeM, message):

        llog_f = open(file, "a")
        llog_f.write("\n" + typeM + ": " + message)
        llog_f.close
```

The code that I am using to utilize the module is as follows:

```
import loggingLocal.__init__

logOb = Logger()

lfile = "logs/log.txt"

logOb.llog(lfile, "test", "testing testing 1 2 3")
```

I expect the file in `logs/log.txt` to contain `test: testing testing 1 2 3` , but I get an error: `Undefined variable 'Logger'` on line three. This makes no sense as I am assigning `logOb` to the `Logger` class, not a variable.

I would like to note that I know I am not doing things in the most efficient way, but thats not what I am here for.

Comment: Yes, you never define `Logger` in that module.

Comment: Your main code file needs to import your file that defines Logger .  - Oh, maybe that's what you think you're doing if "loggingLocal.py" is the name of the file containing Logger.  In that case, you just want to import the symbol Logger, not its __init__ method.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you import a module, you get only the module's name added to your local namespace, not all of the contents of the module (though you can get that if you specifically ask for it).

So if you do `import loggingLocal` (the `__init__` part is not needed, more about it below), you'll only get the name `loggingLocal` in your main module's namespace. To access the `Logger` class within it, you need to use `loggingLocal.Logger`.

Or you can specifically state specific names that you want to copy from the imported module into your own namespace, using the alternative import syntax `from some_module import some_name`. In your case, you'd probably want `from loggingLocal import Logger`. You can give multiple names if you want, or you can give a `*` instead of any names, in which case you'll get either whatever names are listed in the module's `__all__` attribute, or every global variable in the other module that has a name that doesn't start with an underscore.

There are some other small errors in your code. One I alluded to above, where you're naming the `__init__` part of the module name in your `import` statement. That's not needed. `__init__.py` is a filename used for the module that makes up the root part of a package. That is, `foo/__init__.py` becomes the `foo` module. If you don't need a package for some other reason (e.g. because you also have `foo/bar.py` and `foo/baz.py`, which can be imported as `foo.bar` and `foo.baz`), you probably shouldn't use that structure. Instead, just rename your `localLogging/__init__.py` file to `localLogging.py` and get rid of the subdirectory.

The other issue is in your implementation of Logger. When you try to close the file you've created in `llog`, you're not actually succeeding. You only reference the `close` method, but never actually call it (you probable wanted to do `llog_f.close()`). I'd recommend using a `with` statement to handle the opening and closing of the file instead:

```
with open(file, "a") as llog_f:
    llog_f.write("\n" + typeM + ": " + message)
```

This code will automatically close the file at the end of the indented block that follows the `with` statement. It will even close the file if there's an exception that causes the block to exit in an abnormal way.

Comment: Everything mentioned in this answer was used, but I get a new error now. It says that my `logs/log.txt` file doesn't exist, but it does exist. Do I need to use the directory from `C:`, or is it a different problem?

Comment: The file name is going to be interpreted relative to the folder you run the program in, so unless `logs/log.txt` is relative to the same location, you should probably use an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

loggingLocal.py

```
class Logger:

    def __init__(self):

        pass

    @classmethod

    def llog(cls, file, typeM, message):

        llog_f = open(file, "a")
        llog_f.write("\n" + typeM + ": " + message)
        llog_f.close
```

main.py:

```
from loggingLocal import Logger

logOb = Logger()

lfile = "logs/log.txt"

logOb.llog(lfile, "test", "testing testing 1 2 3")
```